# VBA:Lock and fill color for selected cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Following is my vba code,where I fill data to the cells,all I have to do is to lock the same cells and put some color for those.

```
//VBA:-
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("book.a.").RefersToRange = doc.getAttribute("a")
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("book.b.").RefersToRange = doc.getAttribute("b")
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("book.c.").RefersToRange = doc.getAttribute("c")
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("book.d.").RefersToRange =doc.getAttribute("d")
```

How to do this?I got to do this to many more cells.
What do you suggest?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many cells? Are they contiguous? If so, we can loop through the range rather than referring to the named ranges. If not, we need to build an array of the names somehow - are they all in the form "book.a."?

This does what you want for one of the cells (you'll need to unprotect the worksheet before unlocking / amending cells, then protect it again when done):

```
Dim strName As String, objName As Name, strID As String

Sheet1.Unprotect
For Each objName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    strName = objName.Name
    If InStr(1, strName, "book", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        strID = Mid(strName, InStr(1, strName, ".", vbTextCompare) + 1, 1)
        With ActiveWorkbook.Names(strName).RefersToRange
            .Value = doc.getAttribute(strID)
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
            .Locked = True
        End With
    End If
Next
Sheet1.Protect
```

Comment: :Thanks for the answer.yeah,they are many,not contiguous.All of them are in one sheet,and 'book.a.' is just name of a cell.What do you suggest for this?

Comment: I've edited the code so that it loops through all names containing "book", then gets the .x. from the name and retrieves `doc.getAttribute("x")`